# Simple way to spec resources routes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Is there a short and dry way to test all the routes generated by *resources :xxx*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As people have outlined before me, generally you don't test routes. However, if you have something complex like a subdomain constraints in your routes file that you want to make *damn* sure are going to go to the right spot, then I'd recommend (with a touch of bias) reading my article on [Testing Rails Requests](http://ruby.ryanbigg.com/post/1679869207/testing-rails-requests).

Comment: I guess generally not testing routes sounds okay with me. It's just that

Comment: @SimonHürlimann just that what? inquiring minds must know! :D

Comment: "As people have outlined before me..." a citation would be nice, especially because your link is dead (modulo the fact, that this answer is four years old now)

Comment: Archive link to article: http://web.archive.org/web/20120430001118/http://ruby.ryanbigg.com/post/1679869207/testing-rails-requests

Answer (score 0):

When you generate a new resource with `rails generate`, functional tests for the standard routes are automatically generated also. To run them, type in `rake test:functionals`.

Note: functional tests will fail (due to default fixtures and tests generated) if you have validators for uniqueness.

Also, as already mentioned, rake routes will display all routes you app recognizes.

Answer (score 0):

You don't generally test routes, as this is something Rails provides and has tests for.  If you want to test that a particular route is working, you should create an integration or functional test that makes a request to the route in question and verify that the correct controller/action gets called.